# Scroll Snap works with mouse but not with touch Js

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, scroll, touch

I made a Page with Scroll Snap and it works perfectly fine on Desktop. But if i switch to a touchscreen, it runs threw the code, stops for the set Timeout and then continues the normal Snap Scroll.

Here is a video that shows the problem better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z1Qc.jpg

It has to do something with the async function or touchmove Listener, because it gets canceled on the first try, but works on the second. The Touch listener function also gets only called once and passes the same Value as the other listeners. **I deactvicated the touchmove listener and every other source of scrolling.
The Problem only occurs if the touchdown and touchup values are different, so basically when i move while touching.**
Here is the function.

```
`async function smoothScroll(posY) {
  ignoreNextScrollEvent = true;

  window.scrollTo({
    top: posY,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });

  try {
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const failed = setTimeout(() => {
        reject();
      }, 2000);

      const scrollHandler = () => {
        if (window.pageYOffset === posY) {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
          clearTimeout(failed);
          resolve();
        }
      };
      if (window.pageYOffset === posY) {
        clearTimeout(failed);
        resolve();
      } else {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    smoothScroll(posY);
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////Calling the function//////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// get starting Position

document.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => {
  startingPosition = e.pageY;
});


// get ending Position
document.addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  endingPosition = e.pageY;

  lastSection = currentSection;

  let distance = endingPosition - beginningPosition;

// Only triggers if it does'nt scroll

  if (!ignoreNextScrollEvent) {

// decide if it schould go up or down

    if (Math.abs(distance) > 40) {
      if (distance < 0) {
        if (currentSection <= section.length - 2) {
          currentSection++;
        }
      } else {
        if (currentSection >= 1) {
          currentSection--;
        }
      }
    }
    disableScroll();
    if (lastSection !== currentSection) {
      let rect = section[currentSection].getBoundingClientRect();

// calling function

      smoothScroll(rect.top + window.scrollY).then(() => {
        ignoreNextScrollEvent = false;

// you can basically ignore this part

        section[lastSection].classList.remove('focused-section');
        section[currentSection].classList.add('focused-section');

        if (currentSection != 0) {
          scrollbar.classList.add('active-scrollbar');

          if (lastSection > 0) {
            scrollbarNumber[lastSection - 1].classList.remove(
              'focused-section'
            );
          }
          scrollbarNumber[currentSection - 1].classList.add('focused-section');

          scrollbarLine.forEach((line) => {
            line.classList.remove('above-focused-section');
            line.classList.remove('under-focused-section');
          });

          if (currentSection > 1) {
            scrollbarLine[currentSection - 2].classList.add(
              'above-focused-section'
            );
          }
          if (currentSection < scrollbarLine.length + 1) {
            scrollbarLine[currentSection - 1].classList.add(
              'under-focused-section'
            );
          }
        }
      });

      if (currentSection == 0) {
        scrollbar.classList.remove('active-scrollbar');
      }
    }
  }
});
`
```

Comment: It appears that the relevant code hasn't been included in the question.  Seeing the code that actually calls the method would be helpful.

Comment: I added the code, but since it is a pointer listener it should be the same for mouse and touch. But mouse works fine and touch does not.